# Detect Desktop availability from Metro application (detect ARM, detect Windows RT system)

Tags: windows-8, arm, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, desktop

This is a question related to [Get OS-Version in WinRT Metro App C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125324/get-os-version-in-winrt-metro-app-c-sharp) but not its duplicate.

Is there any option to detect from a Metro application whether there is the desktop feature available on the system? I understand that detection of the OS version is not supported and that is OK imo.

However my metro app needs to know whether there is a Desktop available on the system it is running on.

By Desktop I mean extendable desktop - desktop, where 3rd party desktop applications can be installed. As we know ARM based units will have the desktop too, but only with Microsoft built-in programs.

Can I distinguish whether my Metro app is running on a ARM based tablet with non-extendable desktop vs on all other (Intel based) devices with extendable desktop?

Comment: what scenario are you trying to solve?  Why would a Store app need to know about the desktop?

Answer (score 3):

After some more extensive search I found [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724340.aspx) method. The hint was right away on SO site - this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115283/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-logical-cpus-on-winrt). This approach seems to be fully supported by Windows Store applications - the App Cert Kit test ran smoothly despite the fact that pinvoke was used.

I ended up with the following code:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(ref SystemInfo lpSystemInfo);

    internal static bool IsArmBased()
    {
        var sysInfo = new SystemInfo();
        GetNativeSystemInfo(ref sysInfo);
        return sysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture == ProcessorArchitectureArm; //ushort 5
    }
```

This seems to be as a solution I was looking for. Please tell me if not or make me aware of whatever problems connected to such an approach. Thank you.

Comment: What happens to your app if, several releases from now, Microsoft decides to release a version of Windows RT for x86 processors (note: this is pure speculation - I have no idea if this is in the plans)? Using the processor architecture seems a poor way of figuring out if the OS you're on allows arbitrary desktop apps.

Comment: I will simply release new version too ;)  But agree it surely is not an optimal solution. However if the philosophy behind says: Do not search for hardware, platform, OS, but search for features, then I would expect that in one of that future version there will be a simple API call to figure out the desktop capability...

Comment: Why? Jeff Brand asked this question above: What would you do differently if you knew you were running on a machine with the ability to run arbitrary desktop apps?

Answer (score 1):

If this is HTML, you can use `window.cpuClass` to get if it's ARM, x86 or amd64.

A non dynamic version is to use target specific architectures rather than AnyCPU, and then use the flavours with #ifdefs to hard code it at build time. You have to submit 3 packages to the store, however.

Comment: Oh, OK, the idea about 3 packages would be a solution. However what are the disadvantages of 3 different packages? More maintenance, maybe more confusion for the final users, and...?

Comment: No confusion for final users. They just install the app from the store and everything is seemless -- they don't know which package they get. For you, you've got 3 packages to upload, and depending on your test philosophy, 3 packages to test.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try {} catch(){} to access those libraries, if anything goes wrong assume the ARM version.

Comment: Which libraries concretely, Rob?