# Detecting the platform of a Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there a possibility to ask at runtime if a Windows Store app (compiled for ARM and x86/64) is executed currently on an ARM-device or more specific on a Microsoft Surface Tablet from within c# or is it necessary to compile two Versions of the same app to behave different on different plattforms?

Comment: Why would you want it to behave differently - This is exactly the reason Microsoft don't provide a way to detect I suspect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via the following code (according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272399/detect-desktop-availability-from-metro-application-detect-arm-detect-windows-r)):-

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(ref SystemInfo lpSystemInfo);

internal static bool IsArmBased()
{
    var sysInfo = new SystemInfo();
    GetNativeSystemInfo(ref sysInfo);
    return sysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture == ProcessorArchitectureArm; //ushort 5
}
```

This does pass the WACK test, test I wouldn't count on it being around forever. Think very hard about why you need this information (is it just for stats, or are you changing the behaviour of your app, if so why!?)

Answer (score 1):

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

Package package = Package.Current;
PackageId packageId = package.Id;

String arch = String.Format("{0}", packageId.Architecture);
```

This will return "X86" or "ARM", depending on the underlying hardware.

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I currently can not test it, however I suspect that PackageId.Architecture will return "neutral" and not the architecture of the executing proc, because there is only one package (see my post).

Comment: Just checked again on a project set to build as "Any CPU", and it does return the underlying architecture.